# Reduce number with percent

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a code check:

```
const transfer = async (  
  amount: string
): Promise<void> => {
  
  if (parseFloat(amount) <= parseFloat('0.01')) {
    amount = String((2 / 100) * amount);
  }
  .......
}
```

In general I want to make a check and reduce the amount with some very small percent. But I get error for this line `* amount);`:

```
TS2363: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this, both string results have to be converted to number. This can be achieved by these 3 method:

1. Unary Operator (+)
2. parseFloat() //Already you used
3. Multiply with number

*1.Using Unary Operator (+) :*

```
const transfer = async (  
  amount: string
): Promise<void> => {
  
  if (+amount <= 0.01) {
    amount = String(+(2 / 100) * +amount);
  }
   // More code here...
}
```

*2.parseFloat() :*

```
  const transfer = async (  
  amount: string
): Promise<void> => {
  
  if (parseFloat(amount) <= 0.01) {
    amount = String((2 / 100) * parseFloat(amount));
  }

  // More code here...
}
```

*3.Multiply with number :*

```
const transfer = async (  
      amount: string
    ): Promise<void> => {
      
      if ((amount*1) <= 0.01) {
        amount = String((2 / 100) * (amount*1));
      }
    
      // More code here...
    }
```

this error most off occurs by too much brackets.you need to try 1 method `Unary Operator (+)`. it help to convert string into number and you don't need to wrap a string value into a brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing `String((2 / 100) * parseFloat(amount));`: you forgot to convert it to a number for arithmetic operations. Also, there is no need to use `parseFloat(0.01)` when you can use `0.01` directly. Your updated code would look like this:

```
const transfer = async (  
  amount: string
): Promise<void> => {
  
  if (parseFloat(amount) <= 0.01) {
    amount = String((2 / 100) * parseFloat(amount));
  }

  // More code here...
}
```

Also, if you want convert to string, a simpler way is to use template literals:

```
if (parseFloat(amount) <= 0.01) {
  amount = `2 / 100 * ${parseFloat(amount)}`;
}
```

Comment: Can you show me the entire code, please?

Comment: Cna you show me solution without template literals, please?

Comment: @user1285928 It's already in the answer...?